# where do I select the terminal in Github?

Tags: github, terminal

First time working in GitHub, and I am not sure how to access to the "terminal". Any idea? Do I need to install it?

Comment: If you are on a Mac: open up the applications folder, then utilities, then you should see an app called terminal. On Windows, this is referred to as the command prompt search for cmd.exe. If that doesn't work search for `Git Shell` or `Git Bash`.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git/ just check out git setup guide

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your platform.

**Windows:**
Right click the start menu and select command prompt. Or search for `command prompt` in the start menu.

**Mac:**
Search for 'terminal' using spotlight.

**Linux:**
Search for 'terminal' in the menu, or use the shortcut `ctrl` + `alt` + `t`

Answer (score 0):

Many people use the commandline, in a terminal to interact with github remote repositories. Depending on the OS you're using, the terminal works in different ways.

In any case, **git** is the application/commandline software your looking for. With git you can create, commit, etc:

```
> git init
> git add -A
> git commit -m 'first commit!'
> git push origin master
```

If you're not terminal-ly inclined, you could try the desktop client: https://desktop.github.com/